# How to run Django on Docker container

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm setting up a django server application on docker. docker runs the container well but the command to run django is not taking by docker.

I've already gone through few youtube videos but none of them worked for me

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6-stretch

MAINTAINER ***

ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /specfolder
WORKDIR /specfolder
COPY ./myfolder /specfolder

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "manage.py runserver"]
```

i've tried placing the command under docker-compose.yml file under

```
commands: sh -c "python manager.py runserver"
```

but none of them worked

docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3"

services:
myapp:
    build:
        context: .
    ports:
        - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
        - ./myfolder:/specfolder
```

requriements.txt

```
django==2.2.4
pandas
xlrd
xlsxwriter
```

as of now under kinematics i am getting the python shell

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 2019-08-31T13:34:51.844192800Z Python 3.6.9 (default, Aug 14 2019, 
13:02:21) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
```

unable to access the 127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/login in the browser.

Comment: how did you know it didn't work? did you see any error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make changes in your **runserver** command.
Change it to

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Your Dockerfile will be something like this

```
# other command
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Make changes accordingly if you are using Dockerfile or docker-compose.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems in your implementation.

1. In `Dockerfile` you have, `CMD ["python", "manage.py runserver"]`. It should be `CMD ["python", "manage.py",  "runserver"]`
2. In compose file `commands: sh -c "python manager.py runserver"` should be `commands: python manager.py runserver`.

   1. a. If you use compose file then `CMD` should be removed from `Dockerfile`

Comment: still no use, when i access localhost:8000 it shows "This site can't be reached" page

Comment: now i am able to run the app, but unable to access it browser

Comment: Watching for file changes with StatReloader
    Performing system checks...
    System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
    You have 17 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until 
   you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
   Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
   September 03, 2019 - 09:02:55
   Django version 2.2.4, using settings 'myproject.settings'
   Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
   Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

Comment: i have changed by composer file to this: 

    ` version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/myproject
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
`